# svn one directory refers to another inside same repository

Tags: svn

For example, I have repository A, inside A I have directory structure like:

- B/C
- X/Y/Z

When the user checks out folder C (which is under B), he also wants to check out the Z folder inside X/Y, and put inside C. How can I config svn to do it?

FYI, they are in the same svn repository.

svn:externals works almost, but there is some problem. For example, now if I set the external link to svn branch_1, if I split the branches to branch_2, I have to manually update the external link. Since in our case, they are always inside same repository, is any better way to handle it?

Comment: `svn:externals` works within the same repository as well as across different repositories.

Comment: Yes, it works at some level. But when I split branch, I have to manual the "svn setprop" again which forces it pointing the same branch, otherwise, it still points to previous branch. I don't want it point to previous branch. How can I make it smart to do what I want?

Comment: You can use relative externals to keep everything looking in the same branch (assuming that both `X` and `B` share a common parent directory) at all times.

Comment: Relative not working for me. I don't always check that X folder. Actually in my case, the user almost always only checks out B. In this scenario, can I still use relative externals?

Comment: Yes, you can still use relative externals and it will do what you want if `X` and `B` share a common parent directory.

Comment: I wont make it work by using all kind variant as it suggested on link http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html    Can you please give more hint?